# Delete table row after adding it dynamically through Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-events

I have an AJAX script that adds an entry to a database, then updates a table shown on the page to include the new row.

The exact code used for adding the row to the table (once the database stuff has been successfully done and has returned data for the variables to be used below) is:

```
var tableis = document.getElementById("fields-table-append");
var last=(-1);
var Tr = tableis.insertRow(last);
var Td1 = Tr.insertCell(0);
Td1.innerHTML=newrecordname2;
Td1.className = 'cellStyle fields-table-row';
Tr.appendChild(Td1);

var Td2 = Tr.insertCell(1);
Td2.innerHTML="<span class='field-type-style-email'>"+newcontenttype2+"</span>";
Td2.className = 'cellStyle fields-table-row';
Tr.appendChild(Td2);

var Td3 = Tr.insertCell(2);
Td3.innerHTML="<span class='field-type-required-no'>"+newisrequired2+"</span>";
Td3.className = 'cellStyle fields-table-row';
Tr.appendChild(Td3);

var Td4 = Tr.insertCell(3);
Td4.innerHTML="<a onclick='javascript:deleteRow("+newrowid2+")';><img class='fields-table-icon' alt='Delete' src='img/zef-delete.png' onmouseover='' style='cursor: pointer;' /></a>";
Td4.className = 'cellStyle fields-table-row fields-table-column-4';
Tr.appendChild(Td4);
```

As you can see, each row has a delete icon at the end, which successfully deletes the row, again using a background AJAX query for the database stuff and then removes the appropriate row in the UI using the following code:

Javascript:

```
function deleteRow(field_id)
{
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete that? It can't be undone."))
{
 $.ajax({
 data:{todelete : field_id},
 type:'POST',
 url: 'background-delete.php',
 success: function (output) {
  var row = document.getElementById(field_id);
  row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
 }
}
}
```

This works perfectly for content that exists when the page is first loaded, but does not work for any extra rows dynamically added during that page load. To get the delete to work for these rows, I have to first refresh the page so that the new rows are pulled from the database properly rather than displaying dynamically.

I assume this is because the dynamic rows don't really exist in the page HTML (they don't show in view source, for example) so aren't properly recognised/registered?

Is there a way I can have these dynamic rows behave the same as rows created on page load, allowing me to show a working delete button without requiring a refresh?

***EDIT WITH MORE INFO, AS REQUESTED:***

On page load I just create the table by looping through MySQL results and outputting like this:

```
<?php
$sqlresultloop = "SELECT * FROM contacts_fields WHERE owner_id = '$user_id'";
$resultloop = $mysqli->query($sqlresultloop);

if(mysqli_num_rows($resultloop) > 0)   // checking if there is any row in the resultset
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultloop))  // Loop thru rows
    {

      ?>

<tr class="field-type-table-border" id=<?php echo($row['unique_id']); ?>>
<td class="fields-table-row"><?php echo($row['field_label']); ?></td>
<td class="fields-table-row"><span class="field-type-style-email"><?php echo($row['date_type']); ?></span></td> 
<td class="fields-table-row"><?php if(($row['is_required']) == 0) { ?><span class="field-type-required-no"><?php print("Not required"); } else { ?><span class="field-type-required-yes"><?php print("Required"); }; ?></span></td>
<td class="fields-table-row fields-table-column-4"><a onclick="javascript:deleteRow(<?php print(($row['unique_id'])); ?>)";><img class="fields-table-icon" alt="Delete" id="fields-table-icon" src="img/zef-delete.png" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;" /></a></td>
</tr>
```

Then I have a button on the page that triggers a modal to add a new entry. I process that and do an Ajax request to add the data to the database. I get back JSON, and handle it in the "success" code like this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {

var $theform = $(this);
var theformid = $theform.attr('id');

e.preventDefault(); //stops page refresh and weird URL shenanigans

if(theformid === 'ex1')
    {
      document.getElementById("myLoader").style.display = "block";

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'background-contact-fields.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function (output) {
       
              //do stuff here when successful
              let str = output;
              
              str = str.substring(1);
              str = str.slice(0, -1);
              const myObj = JSON.parse(str);
              newrecordname2 = myObj["fieldlabel"];
              newcontenttype2 = myObj["datatype"];
              newisrequired2 = myObj["isrequired"];
              newrowid2 = myObj["newrowid"];
```

It all works fine, I get back the information I expect. I then append it to the existing table using the first block of code I showed in this question, using the values as set above. It comes immediately after the `newrowid2 = myObj["newrowid"];` line. That's it.

Everything works just as I want, except making the delete button work on the new row without a page refresh. It's not the end of the world, I can just not show it until page refresh. But it would be nice if it worked.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using both vanilla JS DOM methods _and_ jQuery? Usually it's best to stick with one or the other. Anyway, the answer is to use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) and attach one listener to a parent element like `<table>` that can listen for events fired from its children (dynamic or otherwise) and call a function if that element is a row delete button.

Comment: And the documentation for jQuery's [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) process.

Comment: the code you posted is fine, the problem must be with your ajax function on adding the new data, if you can post your whole code, we could give you an answer
(although you can delete your appendChild functions, insert cell will automaticaly do that for you)

Comment: @Andy because I'm hacking this together with stuff I find online! I'm sure it's a mess all over the place, but getting it working quickly was my priority and I'm nothing close to resembling a coder of any kind.

I'd read the event delegation stuff already, but tbh it's a bit of a mystery to me. But I appreciate the pointer, thanks :)

Comment: @covgdn what does the data you're getting from the database look like? I'm assuming it's JSON? Can you add a sample to your question?

Comment: @Andy added an edit, not sure if that helps. Yes, I get JSON back from the Ajax calls and use that to add the new rows dynamically, but get the initial table data directly from MySQL on page load.

Comment: @covgdn I added an answer that should help show you how event delegation works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic principle of event delegation is that DOM events "bubble up" the DOM. Instead of adding listeners to each element you can add *one* to a parent element that "catches" or listens out for events from its child elements. For example: instead of having listeners on every one of the rows that you add, add one to the table body to listen out for its child element events when they're fired, and then calls a function.

Here's a rather contrived example that might help you understand how it works. The example uses a lot of relatively new JS tech but don't worry too much about that - it's really the event delegation process that I'll going through, and I'll add links to documentation for everything at the bottom of the answer. Everything can be swapped out for code that you're more used to.

```js
// We have a table in our markup already so we need to
// select the `tbody` element, and then assign one listener
// to it. The listener will catch events from its children
// (here: the buttons in the rows), and then call the
// `handleClick` function
const tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
tbody.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

// Set up some data - this would be your data from your
// endpoint...
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Rita', age: 18, location: 'Bradford' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Sue', age: 19, location: 'Bradford' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Bob', age: 35, location: 'Bradford' }
];

// ...but in this example we're using a "mock" API
// request to deliver a stringified version of that
// data to the app - when the function is called it waits
// for two seconds to mimic the latency of the request
function mockApi() {
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const json = JSON.stringify(data);
      res(json);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

// A function that creates some row HTML from
// the data (an array). It `map`s over the data
// and returns a string of row information (using a
// template string to add in the object values)
// The last cell includes the delete
// button. Because `map` itself returns a (transformed)
// array we need to join it up into a string at the end.
function createRows(data) {
  return data.map(obj => {
    return `
      <tr>
        <td>${obj.name}</td>
        <td>${obj.age}</td>
        <td>${obj.location}</td>
        <td>
          <img
            data-id="${obj.id}"
            class="delete"
            src="https://dummyimage.com/100x25/bfa6bf/000000&text=Delete" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    `;
  }).join('');
}

// The function that is called when the `tbody`
// listener "catches" an event from one of its children.
// First it checks to see if the element that fired the event
// is a button. If it is a button we find the closest parent row
// to that button, and remove it from the DOM
function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('img.delete')) {
    e.target.closest('tr').remove();
    console.log(`Deleting: ${e.target.dataset.id}`);
  }
}

// The main function that calls the mock API
// parses the JSON into an object, and then calls
// `createRows` with that data which returns the HTML.
// We then attach all the HTML to the `tbody` element.
async function main() {
  const response = await mockApi();
  const data = await JSON.parse(response);
  const html = createRows(data);
  tbody.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
}

main();
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
thead { background-color: #efefef; text-transform: uppercase; }
td { padding: 0.25em; border: 1px solid #efefef; }
img.delete:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Age</td>
      <td>Location</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Additional documentation

- [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [How to use promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises)
- [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)
- [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)
- [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises#async_and_await)

Comment: Thanks, this has been really helpful. I just slotted your code in as dummy stuff for now to work from. It works, the rows appear. It does throw an error in JS though, which breaks a few other things. See below:

```app-bottom.js:47 Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function
    at createRows (app-bottom.js:47:6)
    at Object.success (contact-fields.php:134:14)
    at c (jquery-3.6.1.min.js:2:28327)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.6.1.min.js:2:29072)
    at l (jquery-3.6.1.min.js:2:80045)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.6.1.min.js:2:82499)```

Comment: Sorry about the dumb formatting, not sure how to do it better. But it's this that it's complaining about: ```function createRows(data) {
  return data
    .map((obj) => {``` when saying ```TypeError: data.map is not a function```. That matches the file/line number etc

Comment: @covgdn if you pop the relevant code (AJAX, sample JSON response, and how you're calling the `createRows` function) into pastebin I'll take a look over it. It maybe that your parsed JSON is an object not an array which is why it giving you an error.

Comment: OK, a follow up @Andy. I hope that's OK.

I have 90% of this working. The only 2 things I can't work out are:

1) How to change the delete button to an image and still have the delete handleClick stuff do its job. I tried a bunch of options, but it stopped triggering the delete. I use an image called "img/zef-delete.png" usually.

AND 2) How to pass an ID to the handleClick function so that I can handle the Ajax part of deleting the record from the database. I can have the relevant record ID as an ID on the row, no problem. But getting it back to the function, I do not know.

Comment: 1) Give the image element a `delete` class and then in the `handleClick` function change `if (e.target.matches('button'))` to `if (e.target.matches('img.delete'))` - you need to match the right element for it to work. @covgdn

Comment: Right @covgdn I've updated the answer with an image. I added some ids to the dataset, and used those in a data attribute on the image element. When the image is clicked that data attribute is picked up in the `handleClick` function by looking at the `e.target`'s dataset. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Flawless, @Andy. Thank you so much. Do you have a Ko-Fi or anything where I can send you a proper thanks. You've saved me hours of stress here.

Comment: All part of the service @covgdn. Donate to your favourite charity instead.